# Is there a way to get the same result as chaining several .next() methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a html which looks roughly like this:

```
<tr id="row">
  <td id="cell_1">Cell 1</td>
  <td id="cell_4">Cell 4</td>
  <td id="cell_8">Cell 8</td>
  <td id="cell_9">Cell 9</td>
  <td id="cell_11">Cell 11</td>
  ...
</tr>
```

I have no way of changing it.  For example, I have a variable `cell`, which points to the jQuery object representing the second `td` and I would like to get the element which is `n` cells after the `cell`. One way to get it would be:

```
var cell = $("#cell_4");

var next = cell;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  next = next.next();
}
```

But I think that wouldn't be the most proper way since it requires `n` amount of "moves" through the DOM. The other way I could think off involves using the `index()` method (not tested so it could contain some errors but I think the method is understandable):

```
var index = $("#row > td").index(cell);
var next = $("row td:nth-child(" + index + n + ")");
```

Is there a "better", built in, way to achieve that result? For example, something which would look like this:

```
var next = cell.nextTimes(n);
```

Comment: Can't you take the ID of the cell you already have stored in the variable and increment it by n, then get the resulting cell by its ID?

Comment: No, because as you can see in the example html, there can be some "holes" between the numbers. For example - if we take `n === 2` and the `cell` points to the first row, we would end up with `$("#cell_3")` instead of `$("#cell_8")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the cells in questions have `id` values, if you can derive the value of the one you want from where you're starting, you can just use `$('#cell_' + derivedValue)`.

But if you can't do that, you can use [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
var next = cell.nextAll().eq(n); // Or `n-1`, depends on what `n` is
```

`nextAll` returns all of the element's *following* (next) siblings, and `eq` reduces the matched set to the element at the given index.

So for example, `cell.nextAll().eq(1)` starting from `cell_1` in your example would return
`cell_8` (`cell_4` would be `cell.nextAll().eq(0)`).

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uwewiq)

Comment: Thank you, the most complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll) method and use the [`:eq(n)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector (or [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method) to select it.

You could write a `nextTimes()` method yourself like this;

```
jQuery.fn.nextTimes = function (n) {
    return this.nextAll().eq(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var next = cell.nextAll(':eq('+n+')');
```

Comment: `next()` does not work like that; this will select the next element *only* if it matches the selector. You should see `nextAll()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you want to do if the current cell plus *n* is beyond the end of the current row, but in a general sense you can get a cell by index *without* jQuery if you use the plain DOM `.cellIndex` property to get the index of the current cell and then just add *n* to that and use the result as an index into the parent `tr` element's `.cells` collection:

```
// given your existing jQuery object for the current cell:
var cell = $("#cell_4");

// cell[0] is the actual DOM element, cell[0].cellIndex is
// its position within the row, so n cells after is:
cell[0].parentNode.cells[cell[0].cellIndex + n]

// or as a jQuery object:
$(cell[0].parentNode.cells[cell[0].cellIndex + n])
```

Or as a dodgy jQuery plugin that I'm sure you can tidy up:

```
$.fn.nextTimes = function(n) {
    var c, i;
    if (this.length > 0) {
        c = this[0];
        i = c.cellIndex + n;
        if (i < c.parentNode.cells.length)
           return $(c.parentNode.cells[i]);
    }
    return $([]);
};


var next = cell.nextTimes(n);
```

Working demo of `.nextTimes()`: http://jsbin.com/atusiy/2/edit

(Obviously `.nextAll()` can do the trick as per the other answers, but the DOM methods should be faster if you do it a lot and if you do do it a lot you'll want your own plugin method anyway...)